# Check if -ObjC linker flag is set from code

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Is there any way to determine if the -ObjC linker flag is set from code? I am looking for something like this:

```
#ifdef OBJC_LINKER_FLAG
NSLog(@"-ObjC linker flag is set.");
#endif
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to check this in code. However, you can add a custom "Run Script" build phase which executes a script before the "Compile Sources" build phase (see below).

In the script you can obtain the build settings variables and perform checks.

Edit: if you want to "return" with an error, exit the script with a non-zero variable, e.g.

```
exit -1
```

this stops the build process.

Otherwise, if the build setting matches your requirements:

```
exit 0
```

The build proceeds.

A bash script could be written:

```
if [[ ${OTHER_LDFLAGS} == *-ObjC* ]]
then
  exit 0
else
  echo "Linker flag -ObjC missing"
  exit -1
fi
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for confirming that.